# Stylesheet has no effect on html (yet bootstrap styles work)

Tags: css, html

For whatever reason I can't seem to get my custom stulesheet to link to the HTML index. Bootstrap and Font Awesome styles work perfectly though

My HTML IS is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <!--  start of scripts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- (bootstrap3) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <!--  end of scripts -->

  <!-- start of stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- font awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- (bootstrap3) Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- (bootstrap3) Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- end of stylesheets -->
</head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS is:

```html
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

And the File structure is:

```html
/root
  /css
    -style.css
  /js
    -scripts.js

  -index.html
```

Comment: Your stylesheet should be at the end of the list.

Comment: what @abidishajia. bootstrap will reset things.

Comment: Your custom stylesheet should come after the bootstrap links in order for it to work. Otherwise bootstrap will override your styles.

Comment: How can you tell anything is working if your body has no content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place your custom stylesheet after the bootstrap stylesheet in your `head`. The browser will read down, so custom stuff always comes last. In your code, Bootstrap would always take precedence over your custom style.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Comment: np - easy mistake to make :)

Answer (score 1):

There is something you need to know about CSS. your style sheets are read by the **order** you have added them. so you should add your own CSS file at the end for keeping them from overriding by previous CSS files.

if you have

`.bg{background:red}` in your first CSS file, and
`.bg{background:green}` in your last CSS file.

whenever you add `.bg` to the elements , the background color will be **green** not red.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can mark your custom css as !important:

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue !important;
}
```

More on specificity here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity